# Why is the margin to the top of my page?

Tags: html, css

**MyPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Color Flash Cards</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>Color Flash Cards</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
body{
    background-color: #31859C;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#header{
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #9838CE;
}
#title{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

**result:**

[image: Ghost Margin]

Where is the margin that is at the top (above the purple) coming from? And what do I need to do to get rid of it? I could use negative values for `margin-top` to do it but is that the "real" solution here?

Comment: Probably default padding from the browser? Try `padding: 0` on `body`.

Comment: Side note: Your doctype is for pages served as application/xml+xhtml and I doubt you are doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All headings have a default margin that can be canceled out with:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Demo: [image: Dabblet Demo]

I would recommend using a css reset code like t[his one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) if you want to avoid these quirks and style them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

One of two things might be causing this:

1. Padding in the body? Add `padding: 0;` to body.
2. The top margin on the `H1`. To combat this add `overflow-hidden;` to `#header`

Adding `overflow: hidden` to the `#header` will cause the header `DIV` to contain it's contents (including the margin on the `H1`).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `margin` of `h1` tag to `0`:

```
h1 { margin: 0; }
```

See [**`jsFiddle demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/XNNpu/).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margins of `html` to **0** as well.

```
html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
You might want to add

```
body{
  padding:0;
 }
```

but that's not the real issue, its the `H1` tag that is spoiling the layout

add this to your css

```
h1{
margin-top:0;
}
```

here is a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhvarma/uBGyK/)

Answer (score 0):

use reset css for default browser setting will be reset.

```
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
enter code here
```